# SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_OTHER

Tags: linux, kernel, arm, process-management, priority

I was trying to change linux process priority using [chrt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chrt). I changed priority of one process to `SCHED_FIFO` from `SCHED_OTHER`. I could see some improvement in the perfomance. I run linux angstrom distribution for my embedded system.

So if I use `SCHED_FIFO` for one process, how other process will get affected? What are the precautions to be taken? I couldn't notice an apparent change in processor utilization. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in `sched_setscheduler(2)`, `SCHED_FIFO` is RT-priority, meaning that it will preempt any and all `SCHED_OTHER` (ie. "normal") tasks if it decides it wants to do something.

So, you should be absolutely sure it is well written and will yield control periodically by itself, because if it decides not to (eg. it wants CPU time) the rest of your system will come to complete halt until such time your RT process decides to sleep (which may be "never").

Comment: I agree with the advice, but there is a limit nowadays (default 95%). http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html